# Themeroller for Jquery is messing up my images

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-themeroller

I am just testing out the themeroller thus threw in random colors to tryout the appearance. It seems to messy up the structure and now my images are kind of stacked onto one another. I have attached the link codes and images to refer. Please advice what I am doing wrong. Thank you.

```
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="newTheme.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile.structure-1.4.2.min.css" /> 
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1"/>
```

How it looked prior to using themeroller:
[image: Initial Image]

After Using themeroller:
[image: newTheme]

The random set up of the theme roller:
[image: theme roller]

New Code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="newTheme.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile.structure-1.4.2.min.css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
```

New image after the change in code: 
[image: new image]

Comment: you appear to be mixing 1.4 css with 1.3 JS.  You need to use consistent versions of the CSS and JS

Comment: Hi, thanks for pointing that out. I have made the changes to match 1.4 JS for both. There is a difference now but still doesn't match the set up of the original w/o the themeroller.